# Formatting these forms correctly

Tags: html, forms, xhtml

I have a situation where nested forms would work great, but apparently nested forms aren't really allowed.

Take this following example:

```
<form method="post" action="bid.php">
   <input type="hidden" value="11111111" name="auction_id">
   <input type="hidden" value="bid_confirm" name="action">                
    <!-- Holder Ends -->
    <div class="holder2">
        <div class="text">
            Quantity:
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" maxlength="6" value="1" class="small" name="quantity">
        </div>
        <!-- Btn Ends -->                                                    
        <div class="contentClear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Holder Ends -->                                                             
    <div class="holder holder3">                                                        
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" maxlength="15" name="max_bid">
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <input type="image" src="images/pixel.gif" class="bid" name="submit">
        </div>
        <!-- Btn Ends -->
        <form method="post" action="make_offer.php?auction_id=11111111">  
            <div class="btn btn_offer">
                <input type="image" src="images/pixel.gif" class="offer" name="submit">
            </div>
            <!-- Btn Ends -->
        </form>                                    
        <div class="contentClear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Holder Ends -->            
</form>
```

You will see from the above where the nesting would be ideal.

Technically I could just close the first form off before the other one starts as all the required fields have been output `auction_id,action,quantity,max_bid` however I wanted to avoid this as then the code starts looking messy as the form would open & end in different sections of the code & that isn't very ideal.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to handle this situation without resorting to Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You could have the second form (to make the offer) an `AJAX` component where you don't submit the form but still send the data properly.  IMO this would be the best approach, but you didn't want to revert to `javascript` (for some reason).

Another option that would work is instead of having the form insert an `iFrame` of a page.  This page would then have your 2nd form on it and would submit.  The issue with this is that you would have to find a way to pass the auctionID to the iFrame.  But if you can do this through URL parameters, then it shouldn't be too bad.

It would look a lot like this I think :

```html
    <!-- Btn Ends -->
    <iframe src="pagewithform2.php?auction_id=1111111" width="xx" height="xx" scrolling="no"/>                                  
    <div class="contentClear"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I ended up just turning the second form into a straight link as it only needed the auction ID which was already being used as a GET variable so no need for a form. :)